# Storing json strings into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> I'm trying to store the gameQuestion each time the function loops through,
>   but when the output goes to the json string it only gives me the last
>   value instead of all the values. I can see all the values when I
>   console.log, but I need to store all the values.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {


url = 'http://streak.espn.com/en/';

request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        var gameQuestion, propVal;
        var json = { gameQuestion : "", propVal : ""};

        $('.gamequestion').each(function(){

            var data = $(this);
            gameQuestion = data.text();
            console.log(gameQuestion);
            json.gameQuestion = gameQuestion;

        });

        $('.mg-check.mg-checkEmpty.requireLogin').each(function() {
            var data = $(this).attr('selectionid');

            propVal = data;
            console.log(propVal);
            json.propVal = propVal;
        });
    }


    fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function(err){

        console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
    });

    res.send('Check your console!');

   });
});



app.listen('8081');

console.log('magic happens on port 8081');

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Your need to store your values but you just overwrite it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change type of property `gameQuestion` in  `var json = { gameQuestion : "", propVal : ""};` to array `var json = { gameQuestion : [], propVal : ""};`  and push in it over iteration

```
$('.gamequestion').each(function(){
    var data = $(this);
    gameQuestion = data.text();
    console.log(gameQuestion);
    json.gameQuestion.push(gameQuestion);
});

console.log(json.gameQuestion);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Declare gameQustion as an array;
`i.e. var gameQuestion = ["",""];` then push each value to the array `json.gameQuestion.push(gameQuestion);`